# >HTTP Status 404 - Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1 on jar deployment

Tags: artifactory

I am currently in the process of upgrading a set of gradle build scripts from gradle 1.3 to 3.4.1.  This includes updating the artifactory plugin to the latest version.  The process was progressing nicely until I got to the Java/Groovy portion of the build.  The scripts are building and publishing the jars to artifactory, but I'm getting a stacktrace on most of the deployments (all jars are successfully deployed to artifactory, not all of the deployments result in the stacktrace).

We're currently running 2.6.5 of artifactory, so my question is about where the problem likely lies.  Would it be in the gradle scripts/artifactory plugin, or would it be because we're waaaay behind in artifactory.  If the answer is the latter, then my time is better spent getting our repository updated, rather than trying to fight with the gradle scripts.

Is there anything in the stacktrace below that might indicate the source of the problem, or is more information needed?

Thanks in advance....

```
Deploying artifact: [imagine the url for jar, removed because I got "this looks like spam" error]
Response received:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report HTTP Status 404 - Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722type Status reportmessage Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722description The requested resource (Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722) is not available.Apache Tomcat/7.0.27


Failed while reading the response from: PUT http://artifactory.myemployer.com:8081/artifactory/debug-local/com/myemployer/unitTest/templateTestFramework/2017.03.30.new/templateTestFramework-2017.03.30.new.jar;build.timestamp=1490904731254;build.name=cfactordebugJava;build.number=20170330new HTTP/1.1
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report HTTP Status 404 - Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722type Status reportmessage Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722description The requested resource (Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA1: 8f01751c92539b9c262b3607888732a3d6965722) is not available.Apache Tomcat/7.0.27; line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1902)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3825)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3747)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2090)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1627)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:220)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.tryChecksumDeploy(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:590)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:548)
        at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:278)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask.deployArtifacts(BuildInfoBaseTask.java:471)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask.prepareAndDeploy(BuildInfoBaseTask.java:398)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask.collectProjectBuildInfo(BuildInfoBaseTask.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:692)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:675)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Deploying artifact: http://artifactory.myemployer.com:8081/artifactory/debug-local/com/myemployer/unitTest/templateTestFramework/2017.03.30.new/templateTestFramework-2017.03.30.new.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: http://artifactory.myemployer.com:8081/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://artifactory.myemployer.com:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/cfactordebugJava/20170330new

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 47.418 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a compatibility issue between the latest version of the gradle plugin and Artifactory 2.6.5, related to the way error messages are reported back from the REST API.
I strongly recommend investing the effort in upgrading your Artifactory to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that might be it.  It's on the to-do list, but I may have to get to it sooner.